# Esperar comando BAT ser executado para continuar

Tags: windows, batch, linha-de-comando

Preciso executar um arquivo bat com o seguinte conteudo:

```
ECHO "Mensagem 1"
copy xxx yyy
ECHO "Mensagem 2"
outro.bat param1
ECHO "Mensagem 3"
copy zzz ooo
```

Porem quando ele executa o outro.bat o meu script não espera ele terminar para executar a mensagem 3 e o comando copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para realizar a execução síncrona em um arquivo bat utilizei o recurso CALL

Ex:

```
ECHO "Mensagem 1"
copy xxx yyy
ECHO "Mensagem 2"
call outro.bat param1 > log
ECHO "Mensagem 3"
copy zzz ooo
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar um tempo de espera(pausa na execução) para prosseguir com o script.

timeout /t 60

No caso acima, vai ter um contagem de 60 segundos para prosseguir com a execução.

Comment: Mas eu não sei quanto tempo vai demorar para executar o outro.bat varia de 30 segundos a 15 minutos.

Comment: Se colocar o time com tempo máximo de 15 minutos não te ajuda?
timeout /t 900

Comment: Não é uma boa opção pois vai gastar tempo desnecessário

Answer (score 0):

ECHO "..."

ECHO "Pressione qualquer tecla para sair!"

timeout /t -1

Dessa forma o script vai aguardar indefinidamente até que alguém pressione qualquer tecla e o script irá fechar!